# Simple method to change DataFrame column type but use a default value for errors?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

Suppose I have the following column.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> a = pandas.Series(['0', '1', '5', '1', None, '3', 'Cat', '2'])
```

I would like to be able to convert all the data in the column to type `int`, and any element that cannot be converted should be replaced with a `0`.

My current solution to this is to use `to_numeric` with the `'coerce'` option, fill any `NaN` with `0`, and then convert to `int` (since the presence of `NaN` made the column `float` instead of `int`).

```
>>> pandas.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    5
3    1
4    0
5    3
6    0
7    2
dtype: int64
```

**Is there any method that would allow me to do this in *one step* rather than having to go through two intermediate states?** I am looking for something that would behave like the following imaginary option to `astype`:

```
>>> a.astype(int, value_on_error=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
pd.to_numeric(a, 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

---

**Option 2**

```
b = pd.to_numeric(a, 'coerce')
b.mask(b.isnull(), 0).astype(int)
```

---

**Option 3**

```
def try_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return 0

a.apply(try_int)
```

---

**Option 4**

```
b = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=int)

i = np.core.defchararray.isdigit(a.values.astype(str))

b[i] = a[i].astype(int)
b[~i] = 0

pd.Series(b, a.index)
```

---

**All produce**

```
0    0
1    1
2    5
3    1
4    0
5    3
6    0
7    2
dtype: int64
```

---

**Timing**
*Code Below*

[image]

```
def pir1(a):
    return pd.to_numeric(a, 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

def pir2(a):
    b = pd.to_numeric(a, 'coerce')
    return b.mask(b.isnull(), 0).astype(int)

def try_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return 0

def pir3(a):
    return a.apply(try_int)

def pir4(a):
    b = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=int)

    i = np.core.defchararray.isdigit(a.values.astype(str))

    b[i] = a[i].astype(int)
    b[~i] = 0
    return pd.Series(b, a.index)


def alt1(a):
    return pd.to_numeric(a.where(a.str.isnumeric(), 0))

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000],
    columns='pir1 pir2 pir3 pir4 alt1'.split()
)

for i in results.index:
    c = pd.concat([a] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(c)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import c, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))

results.plot(logx=True, logy=True)
```

Comment: Should I interpret the fact that Option 1 is identical to my current solution that my original solution is probably OK?

Comment: Yes!  It is definitely ok.  But what is your objective.  Simpler code or faster execution?

Comment: That's a great question. My primary objective was simpler code. To me, the solution I posed requires me to think for a moment because while the behavior is self-documenting the intent is not. I feel the intent is more explicit with a method that explicitly substitutes a value on conversion.

Comment: I also have never loved the fact that `to_numeric` is not a method of a `Series` but rather a module-level function, so I tend to try and find solutions that do not use it.

Comment: Although, in my performance testing I do find that type conversions of columns are some of my longest running calls so reducing from 2 to 1 type conversion is also a win.

Comment: Though clumsy, **Option 3** matches your intent, as far as I understand.  Though I'd expect it to be slower.

Comment: I fully agree that the intent is *very* clear with Option 3.

Comment: **Option 4** is an attempt to reduce the size of conversions overall.  It reduces it to less than one.

Comment: It just goes to show... don't make any assumptions about performance without profiling! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
a.where(a.str.isnumeric(),0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    5
3    1
4    0
5    3
6    0
7    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(a.where(a.str.isnumeric(),0))` also works

Comment: While this isn't one step, it's probably going to be as good as it gets for what I am looking for. It at least has only one type conversion instead of two.